# Can I use modules in a web worker?

Tags: javascript

For the first time, I developed a project using the "new" native `import` and `export` features and all my modules are written that way.

Well now I want to add a feature to run some of those modules via a web worker. Is it doable without duplicating the modules and altering them (creating a maintenance nightmare)?

For example, I know about 
[the `importScripts` functionality in web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts), but the documentation doesn't say anything about it playing nice with module exports.

So if I have a file like this:

```
import // ... resources ...

function doStuff() {
    // do stuff that a web worker can handle, no DOM manip, etc
}

export default doStuff;
```

Can it be seamlessly utilized inside a web worker, assuming none of its components do things that a web worker can't?

If not, could I use something like webpack to bundle the module together into a single web worker file? Is there some common way of doing this?

Comment: Note that specs planned to place a new Option parameter on Worker constructor where you'd be able to tell if it is a *module* worker or not : https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/e3a5bb757f64374c37d8c4528c01298463ef0b2a It seems no browser implements this yet though.

Comment: @Kaiido cool to know thanks

Answer (score 4):

Didn't plan on self answering this but I did some testing on that [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) idea and yes, even if you don't want to use webpack for your whole project, which I don't, you can use it with the web worker being your entry point, pull all the needed modules into one file with webpack, and use the output file as a web worker.

I wasn't sure webpack was going to output a web-worker-friendly file, but it does and so you can use something like this and it'll work perfectly if you webpack it:

```
import testFunc from './test.js';

onmessage = function(e) {
    testFunc();
    console.log('Message received from main script:', e.data);
    var workerResult = 'hello world';
    console.log('Posting message back to main script');
    postMessage(workerResult);
}
```

I tested this and it absolutely works when ran as a web worker in web packed form.

Comment: What was your `webpack.config.json`?